# How to build object using C++ vector library in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

so I have some working code that calls gcc in a makefile. I then add my own class that uses the c++ vector stl, and I want to compile the same object.

If I just run the same command, I get an error:

```
fatal error: vector: No such file or directory
#include <vector>
```

If i try to use g++ instead to compile, I instead get a million errors, so I'm guessing that I shouldn't do that.

I googled how to add a c++ library to a gcc call, and I was told to use

```
gcc -lstdc++
```

However, that doesn't seem to have any effect. How can i go about building this object?

Would using g++ be the standard way? If I use g++ instead of gcc it seems like there are many conversion errors of this type:

```
globals.c:1381:50: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Global*' [-fpermissive]
 struct Global *g = calloc(1,sizeof(struct Global)); /* allocate viewer context */
```

as well as an error of previous declaration:

```
d:\mingw\include\getopt.h:46:12: error: previous declaration 'int getopt(int, char* const*, const char*)' here
 extern int getopt( int, char * const [], const char * );
```

Comment: `-lstdc++` links to the C++ standard library but `<vector>` is not a "library" it's a header. The reason you couldn't include it definitely is because you didn't use `g++`, so if using g++ gives millions of errors  then it means you need to fix your C code to be valid C++ code. Otherwise you aren't going to be able to use the C++ `<vector>` header.

Comment: You should compile with `g++ -Wall std=c++11`

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few issues here. First, the "gcc" executable will compile both C and C++ code, but it typically determines whether it should compile as C or C++ based on the file suffix. In your case, it appears to have tried to compile "globals.c" as a C source file instead of a C++ source file. The C compiler does not include the proper directory in the list of internal include paths so it will not even try to open the <vector> include. To compile as C++, you can force it with g++ or by changing the name of your source file to have a .cpp or .C suffix.

If you have more than one source file, then you are going to have more work to do. You will probably either need to compile everything with the C++ compiler, or will need to learn about "extern 'C'" and fix the interfaces between C++ and C. This may be more trouble than it is worth.

Next, you will need to address all of the errors in your compilation. It looks like the main problem you show has to do with typecasts. Those were more permissive under C than C++.

I would suggest that you take out the vector code, and keep using a pure C solution in your case. You have to perform the memory management yourself, but it isn't too hard. I have used realloc() in the past to resize memory. You'll need to keep track of a pointer to the allocated memory, the number of allocated objects and potentially the total size of the buffer.

Comment: i followed your suggestion, but there remains one thing I am curious about.  Originally the makefile that was building GTKWave used g++ instead of gcc in the final step. Is there a reason to do this in an app that uses almost all C code? Is it necessary to use g++ when you wish to use a c++ code in your code? I am wondering why this was necessary. gtk uses c code, so the only thing i can think is that perhaps an external library used c++ code.

Comment: The main difference between using g++ and gcc for linking is that g++ links to some of the standard libraries that are required for C++, while gcc only links to what is needed to compile a C program. For example, on Linux, g++ adds "-lstdc++ -lm" to the link line. There are some other differences too, such as g++ adding --eh-frame-hdr to the linker command-line. It sounds like g++ was used to link because some C++ libraries are being used. I would probably keep linking with g++. As a test, you could try linking with gcc, but I think you may get some unresolved symbols.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is because there is no automatic conversion from `void *` to other pointer types in c++. Which is not the case in c, so the code would compile correctly with a c compilier, to solve that you just need to cast the return value like this

```
Global *g = reinterpret_cast<Global *>(calloc(1,sizeof(Global)));
```

also notice that you don't need `struct` for declarations in c++.

I'd recommend the `new` operator, because if you add a constructor to `struct Global` it will automatically invoke the cosntructor, also

```
Global *g = new Global;
```

notice however that unlike `calloc()` the struct members here are not initialized to `0`.

The important thing to know is that **c** and **c++** are different languages, you can easily write code that would compile with a c compiler but not with a c++ compiler, like the code above, the other way it's even easier.

Comment: hmm that makes it sound like I shouldn't use g++ since the entire code base was designed to use gcc before and assumes that this conversion is valid. Thanks for letting me know though. Do you know why the same code would give a previous declaration error in C++ but not in C? Unfortunately I will probably have to avoid using g++ then unless I can't find any other way because the amount of code that would need to change is way too much.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet that probably requires taking a look at the `getopt.h` header file. And if you want to work with c and c++ in the same project you can, just separate the c source from the c++ source, create a Makefile to compile it correctly, although **gcc** does use the file extension to guess what compiler to use. And whenever you need a c function in a c++ program just use `extern "C" FunctionPrototypeHere;` and it will work.

Comment: hmm it seems that I need to look into exposing a full C++ class in C or something.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet Using c++ in c can't be done, using c in c++ is possible.3